# What does "overpowered" do in Time Clickers?

Tags: time-clickers

What does "overpowered" mean in Time Clickers?

[image: showing overpowered in Time Clickers]

Answer (score 3):

From a Reddit post on [r/TimeClickers](https://www.reddit.com/r/TimeClickers/comments/3p6ijs/overpowered/?) (emphasis mine):

> Overpowered activates when your team dps is 10^7 times higher than the
>   wave dps and has the effect of **reducing the time between each wave**.
>   The higher above this threshold, the stronger the effect, up to a
>   point. It's worth leaving your starting wave at the minimum level and
>   leveling your starting gold significantly to boost yourself through
>   the early levels very quickly. Additionally, you clear waves fast
>   enough that you can build up a significant timer of active abilities
>   before running out. I currently have overpower until around level 250
>   which leaves me with close to 10 minutes of ability time.

Comment: I saw that too, but "build up a significant timer of active abilities before running out" doesn't fit the current build of the game's mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever see "overpowered", then your starting level is too low. You are wasting your time compared to starting at a higher level.